# Android remove and add to ArrayList in between activities

Tags: java, android

I'm making my first android app and here's where i'm stuck.
I have an activity A which requires 4 players to be picked.
I'm passing to the activity PickPlayer `1`,`2`,`3`,`4` according to which player i want to fill.

```
ImageButton addp1 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.player1);
addp1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), PickPlayer.class);
        i.putExtra("playersList", playersList);
        startActivityForResult(i, 1);
    }
});
```

On the `PickPlayer` activity i have a list which is populated and each item receives a listener.

```
    final ArrayList<Player> playersList = (ArrayList<Player>)getIntent().getSerializableExtra("playersList");
    lv.setAdapter(new PlayerItemAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, playersList));
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View view, int position, long arg) {
            player = playersList.get(position);
            playersList.remove(position);
            Intent intentMessage = new Intent();
            intentMessage.putExtra("player", player);
            intentMessage.putExtra("playersList", playersList);
            setResult(RESULT_OK, intentMessage);
            finish();
        }
    });`
```

The above works fine by creating the `playersList` on activity A and passing it through from one to another each time and removing the player from the playerList on click. 
Problem is if a player is chosen by mistake he needs to be put back into the list again once replaced by someone else.

Any suggestions on implementing this ?
One way i thought of is to pass from activity A to `PickPlayer` the player ( if one is assigned already at his position ) and readding him to the `playerList` again but i'm sure there's a better way for it.
I'm new to android so i have no idea about resources and best practises.
( example passing an object through activities or an id and run a db query).

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is the best way to accomplish this but i'm going to share with you.

I move the `arrayList` with the players back and forth in between the activities.
Once the player is sent back it's removed from it and kept in an object `player1`,`player2`,`player3` etc etc.

So if the user clicks the button that has already a player assigned to it i simply add that player again into the list and pass the `arrayList` as i would do if it was empty.

Answer (score 3):

IMO, you'll achieve best results with a singleton class (or methods on Application instance - [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/708012/how-to-declare-global-variables-in-android) a good stackoverflow question about it).

Your array would be an internal member of the singleton and have an boolean attribute to indicate if a player is already picked or not. Some methods using this attribute can be implemented like:

- `List<Player> getPickedPlayers()`
- `List<Player> getNotPickedPlayers()`
- `void setPlayerPicked(Player player)`
- `void setPlayerNotPicked(Player player)`
- and so on...

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 2):

When you send object through an Intent's bundle (`i.putExtra("playersList", playersList);`), it is marshalled and then unmarshalled on the other side (the new activity). This mean you have 2 instances of ArrayList and its content (one in each activity). If you wish to share data between activity A and activity B, I suggest you store it on an Application instance or by using a singleton.

If your data is coming from a database, you can pass the id through the intent, and get the list of players and the special player with a database query.

Comment: It is coming from a database but using that method i still have to pass the list front and back right ? I'm looking for any alternatives.

PS: Would you suggest passing a player `object` to an activity or pass the id and then run a query to get the players info ( `object` )

Comment: If you need the data from the database in both activities, I would suggest either making it a singleton or querying the data in both activities. 

Regarding the player instance, both solutions are okay as long as a Player is not a big object that will take a long time to marshal.